# Is there a way to check the value of an AWS RDS Oracle hidden parameter value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, parameters, amazon-rds, hidden

Is there a way to check the value of an AWS RDS Oracle Database hidden parameter value? The following approaches do not work.

1.

```
SQL> show parameter "_high_priority_processes"
SQL>
```

2. 

```
SQL> select value from v$parameter where name = '_high_priority_processes';

no rows selected
```

3. 

Connected as the RDS master account.

```
select
v.ksppstvl
from sys.x$ksppi i
join sys.x$ksppcv v
on i.indx = v.indx
where i.ksppinm = '_high_priority_processes';

join sys.x$ksppcv v
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

These approaches do work if the parameter has been set to a non-default value.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to contact AWS support. They are SYSDBAs, not you.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm afraid you have to contact AWS support. They are SYSDBAs, not you.

Checking the value of a hidden parameter in an [AWS RDS Oracle Database](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/oracle/) can indeed be a challenge, since the [RDS environment](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/) is... restricted: in AWS RDS, you don't have the same level of access as in a traditional Oracle database, which limits your ability to query certain system views and tables.

All I can find is [this article](https://success.qualys.com/discussions/s/question/0D52L00004TnxdzSAB/preparing-an-oracle-12c-rds-database-for-a-qualys-scan) which mentions:

> By the way, the documentation attached suggested the Views were created from a SELECT on the `SYS` tables (`SYS.X$KSPPCV` and `SYS.X$KSPPI` respectively), but on closer inspection these sub tables did not exist in my 12c RDS databases.
>
> I found these related tables instead (`STATS$X_$KSPPSV` and `STATS$X_$KSPPI`) which I plugged into the View DDL below, but still failed on a permission issue.

So:

a/ the `STATS` table might be a better candidate
b/ but permissions issue might still be a problem